# Security vulnerability analysis tool for Python command line application?

Tags: python, sast

I'd like to analyze if my Python command line application suffers from known security vulnerabilities (preferably with a tool written in Python, free Python cross-platform for Ubuntu Linux, Mac OS X, Windows 10). Right now I am using the static analyzer [bandit](https://github.com/PyCQA/bandit) which performs analysis based on the abstract syntax tree. I know another static analyzer [pyt](https://github.com/python-security/pyt) which analyzes the abstract syntax tree, generates the control flow graph (CFG) and analyzes the CFG. However as far as I know it is meant to be run with a web framework specific adapter. Is `pyt` suitable/adaptable for/to command line applications as well? Does someone know other Python security vulnerability analysis tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pyt` is suitable for command line applications when using the adapter `Every` via option `-a` e.g. `pyt -a Every -r <package>`. The adapter `Every` restricts to inputs ("triggers") which include the command line app specific input `sys.argv`. (Web framework specific adapters consider framework specific inputs /"triggers" as well which are not required in case of a command line applications.) For more info refer to [this pyt repository issue](https://github.com/python-security/pyt/issues/176).